# Ecto: multiply changesets in one transaction

Tags: transactions, elixir, repeat, ecto

I have following code:

```
MyModel.changeset(data)
|> Repo.insert()
```

I would like to insert 3 times the same row to `MyModel` in a single transaction. Does Ecto have something like:

```
repeat_times(3, MyModel.changeset(data))
|> Repo.insert()
```

?

Comment: In a single transaction **or** with a single database query? The former is easy with [`Ecto.Repo.transaction/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:transaction/2). The latter is impossible out of the box.

Comment: Why not just something like this?

```
changeset = MyModel.changeset(data)
Repo.insert(changeset)
Repo.insert(changeset)
Repo.insert(changeset)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, Ecto 3.x doesn't give you something like that out of the box...

If you're looking for an insert_all type operation, have you checked out [Repo.insert_all](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:insert_all/3)? That's the closest function I can think of that might give you what you're looking for. You'd have to write your own custom function or something to manually construct the list of repeat "MyModel" records. And if you wanted to incorporate changesets, you'd again have to make your own function.

Comment: But it doesn't work with changesets. You'd have to perform validations and that sort of things separately

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html? It actually operates multiple functions and performs them in a single db transaction.